# Como extrair informação de um XML (de nota fiscal) e salvar num csv?

Tags: python, xml

Dentro do xml de nota fiscal tem várias `<tag>` text e eu quero a da chave da nota fiscal. Essa chave possui 44 dígitos (números) e o Python tá colocando espaço/vírgula entre cada número

Eu quero extrair a chave da nota fiscal dentro de um XML pra todos os XMLs de uma determinada pasta e salvar cada chave uma embaixo da outra num arquivo CSV.

A chave da nota tem 44 números, e é referenciada pela tag `{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}chNFe`. Fiz o código abaixo:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import csv

pasta = 'C:/Users/-caminho da pasta com os xmls-'
pasta_csv = pasta + '/lista_xmls.csv'
lista_xmls = []

for filename in os.listdir(pasta):
    if filename.endswith('.xml'):
        xml_file_path = os.path.join(pasta, filename)   
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)       
        root = tree.getroot()               
        for item in root.iter():             
            if item.tag == '{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}chNFe': 
                lista_xmls.append(item.text)   

with open(pasta_csv, 'w', newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ' ')  
    write.writerows(lista_xmls)
```

No código acima do with eu acessei a estrutura de cada XML (que é dividida em vários  texto, um por linha), e adicionei o texto associado ao valor chNFe à `lista_xml` pra todos os xmls de dentro da pasta que eu quero

O output organiza cada chave da nota fiscal (44 dígitos) em uma linha, como o esperado. Porém, cada um desses 44 dígitos ficam separados por um espaço simples (vou encurtar):

```py
2 1 8 2 0 1 8 0 3 0 4 8 5 1 2 0 1 4 5 4 1
3 0 2 0 0 0 9 0 7 6 0 9 7 5 3 2 1 2 4 1 7
```

Se eu fizer a linha do `write = csv.writer` sem o `delimiter = ' '`, o output fica com os 44 dígitos separados por vírgulas

O problema deve estar a partir do with, pois se eu printar a lista_xmls antes do with a lista_xmls fica conforme o esperado:

```js
['89405289742893', '8396724769234', '127836776324', '248907297439278', '2380742376942']*
```

Encurtei/troquei os 44 dígitos das chaves da NF por confidencialidade das informações

Answer (score -1):

`writerows` espera receber como entrada uma lista de listas (mais precisamente, um iterável de iteráveis). Cada lista interna dentro da lista externa será uma linha no CSV. Cada elemento de uma lista interna será um item da linha do CSV. Por exemplo, o seguinte código:

```py
import csv

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

with open("foo.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)  
    write.writerows(l)
```

gera um arquivo `foo.csv` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Você está mandando uma lista de strings. Então o `writerows` vai escrever uma linha para cada string. Mas cada string será tratada como uma lista interna. E como uma string se comporta com uma lista de caracteres, cada caractere será considerado um item diferente nessa linha do CSV.

Se você deseja um CSV com apenas uma linha, e cada elemento dessa linha é uma chave de nota fiscal, você deve usar o método `writerow` (sem o `s` no final):

```py
import csv

lista_xmls = ['89405289742893', '8396724769234', '127836776324', '248907297439278', '2380742376942']

with open("lista_xmls.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)  
    write.writerow(lista_xmls)
```

O código acima gera um arquivo `lista_xmls.csv` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
89405289742893,8396724769234,127836776324,248907297439278,2380742376942
```

Comment: é possível deixar cada sequencia de 44 dígitos numa linha diferente ?
89405289742893 \n
8396724769234
etc?
tentei newline = ',' e não foi
tbm tentei com um for e não foi

Comment: Nesse caso você deve usar `writerows` e cada chave deve ser o único item de sua própria lista interna, ou seja `[['89405289742893'], ['8396724769234'], ['127836776324'], ['248907297439278'], ['2380742376942']]`.